# Receive UDP request on one port and send response through another port

Tags: c, linux, udp

UDP is a connection-less protocol. In my server, I am using two sockets in listening mode:

```
sfd3000=CreateUDPSocketAndListen(3000);
sfd14000=CreateUDPSocketAndListen(4000);
```

I am using

```
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
```

to create the sockets.

I am receiving the request using one socket

```
 recvfrom(sfd3000, reqbuff,1024, 0,(struct sockaddr *)&clientinfo, (socklen_t *)&sinfolen);
```

Can I use the other listening socket to send the response, using the same clientinfo structure

```
sendto(sfd4000,respbuff,resplen, 0,(struct sockaddr *) &clientinfo, sinfolen);
```

Is this possible in UDP as it's a connection-less protocol?

Comment: What do you mean "listening socket"? `listen()` can not be used with UDP sockets. Do you mean reading/receiving?
Yes, you can use `sendto()` to send anywhere you want by providing any destination address.

Comment: Why? Why can't you send the response over the socket that received the request? Why confuse the clients? What's the problem here?

Comment: sorry for the delay in response. The problem is i am trying to send response from another machine. Receiving request in one and sending all response from another machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need not to listen for UDP protocol.
You can just open and block in read if want to read some data / you can just write your data after open.

`In short you can send response through another port`